# How to select columns in dataframe with quotes in name in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I tried to access columns `"accession"  "database"  "disease"   "ec.code"   "omics_type"    "species"` using

```
fileDf.select("\"accession\"","\"database\"","\"connections\"")
```

but still getting error

```
root
 |-- "accession"    "database"  "disease"   "ec.code"   "omics_type"    "species"   "tissue"    "citations.x"   "coding.x"  "ensembl.x" "go.x"  "intact.x"  "kegg.compound.x"   "kegg.glycan.x" "kegg.pathway.x"    "kegg.reaction.x"   "metabolights.x"    "ncbi.x"    "pubchem.compound.x"    "pubchem.substance.x"   "reactome.x"    "reanalysis.x"  "rnacentral.x"  "sgd.x" "sra.x" "uniprot.x" "ajs.connectivity.score"    "citations.y"   "coding.y"  "ensembl.y" "go.y"  "intact.y"  "kegg.compound.y"   "kegg.glycan.y" "kegg.pathway.y"    "kegg.reaction.y"   "metabolights.y"    "ncbi.y"    "pubchem.compound.y"    "pubchem.substance.y"   "reactome.y"    "reanalysis.y"  "rnacentral.y"  "sgd.y" "sra.y" "uniprot.y" "connections": string (nullable = true)

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`"accession"`' given input columns: ["accession" "database"  "disease"   "ec.code"   "omics_type"    "species"   "tissue"    "citations.x"   "coding.x"  "ensembl.x" "go.x"  "intact.x"  "kegg.compound.x"   "kegg.glycan.x" "kegg.pathway.x"    "kegg.reaction.x"   "metabolights.x"    "ncbi.x"    "pubchem.compound.x"    "pubchem.substance.x"   "reactome.x"    "reanalysis.x"  "rnacentral.x"  "sgd.x" "sra.x" "uniprot.x" "ajs.connectivity.score"    "citations.y"   "coding.y"  "ensembl.y" "go.y"  "intact.y"  "kegg.compound.y"   "kegg.glycan.y" "kegg.pathway.y"    "kegg.reaction.y"   "metabolights.y"    "ncbi.y"    "pubchem.compound.y"    "pubchem.substance.y"   "reactome.y"    "reanalysis.y"  "rnacentral.y"  "sgd.y" "sra.y" "uniprot.y" "connections"];;
'Project ['"accession", '"database", '"connections"]
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Relation["accession"   "database"  "disease"   "ec.code"   "omics_type"    "species"   "tissue"    "citations.x"   "coding.x"  "ensembl.x" "go.x"  "intact.x"  "kegg.compound.x"   "kegg.glycan.x" "kegg.pathway.x"    "kegg.reaction.x"   "metabolights.x"    "ncbi.x"    "pubchem.compound.x"    "pubchem.substance.x"   "reactome.x"    "reanalysis.x"  "rnacentral.x"  "sgd.x" "sra.x" "uniprot.x" "ajs.connectivity.score"    "citations.y"   "coding.y"  "ensembl.y" "go.y"  "intact.y"  "kegg.compound.y"   "kegg.glycan.y" "kegg.pathway.y"    "kegg.reaction.y"   "metabolights.y"    "ncbi.y"    "pubchem.compound.y"    "pubchem.substance.y"   "reactome.y"    "reanalysis.y"  "rnacentral.y"  "sgd.y" "sra.y" "uniprot.y" "connections"#10] csv
```

How should I select columns in dataframe with quotes in name in spark?

Comment: I see the problem here. You have one column in your dataframe with all the names. Can you check your dataframe schema ??

Comment: thanks for reply actually this file was separated by tab and I didn't mention delimiter , first line was schema itself and it was only considering all columns as single column only, thanks for catch

Comment: Ahh.. I should have answered instead of commenting. Stupid me :)

Comment: u can do this now even isnt it ?